# Speeding up workflow of generalizing OpenStreetMap road data?

Tags: openstreetmap, road, generalization

Whenever I want to use OSM data for medium scale maps (e.g. 1:200.000) I run into problems.

On the screenshot below one can see the orange street that goes from north to south. It has the attribut highway=primary. I created the "orange road category" by merging these highway-attributes: primary, primary_link, secondary, secondary_link, trunk, trunk_link. This will be the main road" category in my final map.

In contrast to that, the red roads belong to categories I don't want to show on the map (residential, service, path, steps, footway, etc.). I want to exclude them.

The problem is that the orange road is interrupted in the middle of the map by a red road, that belongs to highway=residential.

Now I can choose between three bad options:

1. Include all "residential" roads, which solves this one problem, but creates many other problems and makes the map messy.
2. Exclude the "residential" road and I have an interrupted street.
3. Edit manually.

I run into this problem many times. It occurs on several other instances in this specific map but also in many other of my map-making processes.

Can you recommend a better workflow for handling OSM road data for medium scale maps?

[image]

Comment: I use OSM data for transportation features routinely in 1:100k scale maps.  I make a working copy of the data with an added column for my own classification values, so can easily edit individual features to put them in class I want to drive the symbology.  I usually populate my classification column wholesale at the start using expressions similar to your symbol classification.
It can be somewhat tedious to reclassify individual features, but you can usually readily see gaps in your roads where edits are necessary.